# Linking font properties on different text layers in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text

I'm looking for a technique in Photoshop which allows me to have a master text layer that's linked to other text layers and changes applied to it are applied to all liked layers (regarding font properties: size, color etc). I want to be able to delink or link additional layers to the master layer at any time. I know about layer filtering I'm not looking for an answer like that. If you have confirmation that this is not possible in photoshop atm, that's an answer as well.

Thanks! 
Adam :)

Comment: Have you tried Paragraph Styles and/or character styles?

Answer (score 1):

@Ádám Krisztián Skovrán:  As @Mamoon mentioned, you need to use "Paragraph and/or Character" Styles. There is no such thing as a "master text layer" but you can create a paragraph/character style that would act as your master. Which you decide to use is based on your use case. Keep in mind that if you create an initial/master style, you will need to apply this style to every text layer you create. That in essence is the "link". Hope this helps.